# SwiftUI Wrapping code in navigation view. Cannot view iPad sizes

Tags: navigation, swiftui, simulator, screen-size, navigationview

In SwiftUI when I wrap all of my code in the NavigationView, I can see me UI on the iPhone screen simulator sizes but not on the iPad sizes. When I remove the NavigationView I can see everything again. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

The navigationView is there but you need to swipe in from the left. Or in landscape, it is always visible too.

You can add `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to make it visible all the time.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```